# Single Cycle datapath to a Pipelined datapath

Tags: cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture

This is regarding the design of a `Single Cycle` datapath implementation that is to be converted to an efficient `Pipeline` implementation.

My question is if the single cycle has a clock speed of `x` Ghz or clock period of `1/x`ns, then should the corresponding pipeline implmentation necessarily have it's stage delays sum equal to the clock period of the single cycle?

That is, if pipeline implementation have five stages with delays as `1ns, 2ns, 1ns, 5ns, 3ns` then is it always true that the corresponding Single Cycle from which the pipeline is implemented would have the clock period of `sum (pipeline stage delays)` or `12ns`?

Will it be different from the sum, then how or what factors govern this?

Thanks.

Comment: Approximately, but you can't always just put latches between parts of a non-pipelined design and use the pieces unmodified.  e.g. the cache and memory access logic would probably need changes.  I'm not sure if modifying an execution unit or other logic block to make it pipe-friendly might make it slower.  But if you took a pipelined CPU and turned it into a non-pipelined CPU, then yeah you could just add up the latency of each stage.

Comment: BTW, if you have a pipeline with a 5ns stage as an outlier, that's slowing down the max clock frequency a lot, so you should probably try to put the latches between stages somewhere else, or split it up into two stages.    Unless you're building a low-power CPU that isn't intended to clock right up to the gate-delay limit, but instead you're pipelining to maintain throughput while reducing the frequency or something.